# Javascript Wait for function to complete the call another inside function

Tags: javascript, html

below is my function I am using "setTimeout(function()" for delay how can I wait the above function to complete and then execute the other function.

```
function first_letter() {
  var myArray = ["A", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "K", "M", "N", "O", "P", "R", "S", "T"];
  var letter = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
  bg_width = xx;
  bg_height = xx;

  load(xx, xx)
  loading()
  make(xxxxxxx)

  setTimeout(function() {
    fillText(xxxxxx)
  }, 1500);

  setTimeout(function() {
    rounded(xxx)
  }, 2000);
}
```

Like in given code. Wait until load(xx,xx) completes then executes make(xxxx).

Comment: use async/await

Comment: If you remove the timeouts, it will all run in the order it's written, but that depends on what load() and make() actually do. Else you'll have to use a callback, promises or async/await.

Comment: `how can I wait the above function to complete` It's unclear what `the above function` is. Is it `fillText()`? And if so, is it asynchronous? What does it do? Please add the relevant code and try to clarify your question.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways this can be achieved, although, its hard to see whats going on in your code example as some of the functions are out of scope. However, i have provided you with some examples below which i have assumed the contents of these functions.

You could try:

- **Callbacks** - [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)
- **Promises** - [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/promise)
- **Async functions** - [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

**Callback example**

Calling `make()` from within `load()`, by passing `make()` as a `callback function`.

```
function load(xx, xx, callback){
    /* load does its thing */

    //callback is invoked - (passed in via args, make)
    callback(xx)
}

function make(arg, callback){
    //make funciton
}

//invoke it!
load('a', 'b', make);
```

**Promise Example**

`load` as a JavaScript `Promise`

```
var load = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do whatever you require in here.
    // when you are happy to fulfil, call resolve. 
    // if error, reject!
    resolve(x); //or
    reject(x);


})
// make function
function make(arg){
    // do something
}

// use it!
load.then((x) => { make(x)}).catch((x) => {console.log(x)})
```

**Async await with promise**

In this example the keyword await inside the async function makes javascript wait untill the promise is settled and returns us the result to be used to invoke the `make()` function.

```
async function load(){
    // contents of the load funciton.
    // call the make function when you have the outcome
    // you expected. for example if you are getting data.
    let getData = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {resolve('xx')})

    let xx = await getData // wait till the getData promise is resolved. 
    make(xx);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Promise object. It represents the eventual completion of an asynchronous operation, and its resulting value.

```
function first_letter() {
    var bg_width = 5;
    var bg_height = 10;

    function load(xx, xy) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            // process your data
            // for example
            var result = xx * xy;
            resolve(result);
        });
    }

    function make(xxxxxx) {
        console.log(xxxxxx);
    }

    load(bg_width, bg_height).then(result => make(result));
}
```